# How to implement GtkOrientable in my custom widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3

How can I implement GtkOrientable in my custom widget, what I've done so far is:

```
class MyOwnWidget(Gtk.Orientable, Gtk.DrawingArea):
    ...
```

when I run Gtk throws:

```
/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gi/types.py:194: Warning: Object class gtkmeter+GtkMeter doesn't implement property 'orientation' from interface 'GtkOrientable'
_gobject.type_register(cls, namespace.get('__gtype_name__'))
```

so which are the correct steps to implement GtkOrientable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GtkOrientable requires the "orientation" property to exist on classes implementing this interface. To do this in Python, you can use GObject.Property:

```
from gi.repository import GObject
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyOwnWidget(Gtk.DrawingArea, Gtk.Orientable):
    orientation = GObject.Property(type=Gtk.Orientation, default=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
```

Also note the order of inheritance, since Gtk.Orientable is an interface it should go after the concrete class you are sub-classing. See also:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Orientable.html